# ASP Session Variables Getting Nulled Sometimes on Load Balanced Server and SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, load-balancing

I have created a web based application running on ASP.Net and Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Standard Edition. The application is hosted locally on IIS. I have two servers on which the application is running and on those two servers, there are SQL Servers in Always On Availablity Group. There is a hardware load balancer that sends the requests using round robin algorithm, so that's why I have set the Session to the database. The machine key is same on both the computers and the IIS Application Pool is set to refresh only once at midnight. The paths of the application is same on both the servers and the SQL Always On is being referenced with the cluster IP.

The problem is that the session variables become null sometimes. There are not many session variables and all are of type String.

This is my web.config part.

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SQLConnectionString" connectionString="server=SERVERIP,PORT;Database=DATABASE;uid=USERNAME;pwd=PASSWORD;Max Pool Size=10000" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" clientIDMode="AutoID" enableSessionState="true" />
  <sessionState mode="SQLServer" allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" sqlConnectionString="SQLConnectionString" cookieless="AutoDetect" timeout="10" />
  <machineKey decryptionKey="DECRYPTION KEY" validationKey="VALIDATION KEY" />
```

This is how I access the Session Variables.

```
//Intermediate steps are omitted obviously like creating captcha, login validation, etc.

Session["captcha"] = captcha.ToString();

if (Session["captcha"].ToString() == txtCaptcha.Text)
{
    //ValidateLogin
    //if credentials are correct
    {
        Session["Uname"] = username.Text.ToLower().Trim();
        Session["HomeDir"] = GetHomeDirectory(Session["Uname"].ToString());
    }
}

// on another page
lblUname.Text = Session["Uname"].ToString();
String homedir = Session["Homedir"].ToString();
```

What would be the reason for the session variable to become null and what would be the solution?

Comment: Is it possible you are not using sliding expirations? It defaults to true but perhaps it's overridden somewhere in your web.config?

Comment: Or your AG is failing over and your session data is actually being stored in TempDB because you installed it using the non-persistent option?

Comment: @JordanBrooklyn I didn't overwrite sliding expiration so I guess it remains as default.

Comment: @DavidBrowne I have used that cmd command where we specify the SQL Server IP, Port and the Database name so that it the session doesn't get stored in the TempDB. But in the AG, there is only one database (my database).

Comment: That’s not definitive.  Check the stored procedures in the database.  In one installation option they write to tables in TempDb, and so the sessions wouldn’t surveve failover or restart.

Comment: I have used `aspnet_regsql.exe -S SERVERIP,PORT -U USERNAME -P PASSWORD -d DATABASENAME -ssadd -sstype c` command. My ASPStateTempSessions and ASPStateTempApplications tables are in my database. Similarly, the StateItem Get, Insert, Update, Remove Stored Procedures are in my database too.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Do I need to put either of the TempDB, Master or MSDB in the Always-on Group?

Comment: No.  Looks like just your custom DATABASENAME would need to be in the AG.  I would test an failover to ensure session state survives to be sure.